# clock became delayed when changing tabs in browser

Tags: javascript

I want to display real-time clock. It is working fine. But when I change tabs for some time then go back to tab with the clock, it became delayed.

Here is what I've tried

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CLOCK</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="clock"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
let clock_div = document.getElementById('clock');

let current_time = new Date('2020-11-13 08:00:00');

renderTime();

function renderTime() {
    clock_div.innerHTML = 
        ( current_time.getHours() == 0 ? "12" : ( current_time.getHours() < 10 ? "0" + current_time.getHours() : ( current_time.getHours() > 12 ? ( (current_time.getHours() - 12) < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + current_time.getHours() - 12 : current_time.getHours() ) ) ) 
        + ':' + ( current_time.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + current_time.getMinutes() : current_time.getMinutes() ) + ' ' 
        + ':' + ( current_time.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + current_time.getSeconds() : current_time.getSeconds() ) + ' ' 
        + ( current_time.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM" );

    current_time.setMilliseconds( current_time.getMilliseconds() + 1000 );
    setTimeout(renderTime, 1000);

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Once a tab is in the background (or a browser window minimized) several browsers will suspend any running process'.  They're resumed when the page is brought back into focus.  The flaw here is you assume `renderTime` will be called every second.. but you don't have that guarantee if it's in the background.  Instead of adding a second and assuming it's triggered every second, collect `new Date()` within `renderTime`.  You might also look at `setInterval` instead of repeat `setTimeout` calls

Comment: No clue why you added that link @GalaxyCat105

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman The Web Workers API (which I linked to) allows a script to run in the background, which the what the OP wants.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 Great thanks. I am pretty sure the OP is inexperienced. As an experienced user, I don't understand why you added the comment. It will be really helpful from next time to add a why. 

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Thanks, I will keep that in mind :)

Comment: Thanks @GalaxyCat105 This is what I'm looking for. This doesn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/28000449/12644556. Coz I do not have the luxury to use new Date() i have trouble setting time on rasp-pi when no internet. I just used it as an example, current_time is something I need to fetch from some network inside my LAN.

Comment: and yeah @PraveenKumarPurushothaman a little information would help. not just a link. It is confusing for inexperienced user like me.

Comment: You do not have the luxury to use new Date? But your code above is using it.....

Comment: sorry @epascarello I'm new. I mean I need to specify the parameter.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/epascarello/7vr8o3se/8/